# Javascript - Calculator needs to display currency symbol

Tags: javascript

Hoping for a quick answer here, so here goes...

I have a very simple Calculator script. Takes an input from 2 boxes and multiplies them by hidden values then displays them in a simple span "Total" tag. Works perfectly, except I need it to display a '£' before the figures.

I don't know if I would be best using a Regular Expression or if there is a simple way for me to prepend the amount shown with a simple '£'.

Here's the code, hope someone can help!

```
$(function () {
    $('#txtTables, #txtIndividuals').on('input', function () {
        var tablePrice = $('#hdnPricePerTable').val();
        var indPrice = $('#hdnPricePerIndividual').val();
        var totalTablePrice = tablePrice * $('#txtTables').val();
        var totalIndPrice = indPrice * $('#txtIndividuals').val();
        $('#total').text(totalIndPrice + totalTablePrice);
    });
});
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: The £ symbol is unique of it will change when country change

Comment: or you can use &pound; Htmlcode of pound

Comment: I don't need it to be seen in any other currency, this one will be just for use in the UK Rahul, thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you aren't performing any calculations on the total just prepend it. The the code you have written and the suggestion below will overwrite any previously contained content to the `#total` element.

```
var totalPrice = parseInt(totalIndPrice, 10) + parseInt(totalTablePrice, 10);

$('#total').html("&pound;" + totalPrice);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I take figure 1 (say, 5 individual tickets at £20 each) and figure 2 (10 tables at £50 each) and it seems to just spit out £100500 instead of the sum of figure 1 and figure 2. Can't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: you must set the priority otherwise the result will be incorrect: `(totalIndPrice + totalTablePrice)`

Comment: It was concatenating the numbers as strings, not actually adding them together. The edit will solve that.

Comment: @DavidBarker - What a guy :) thanks everyone but I'll accept this as the answer as it does exactly what I need :) thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

you could use `&#163;` or `&pound;` for showing that symbol before the result

Answer (score 0):

I would not add it into the field.

You can make it different way: simply show it over the input.

See [example](http://jsbin.com/huzum/1/) just to see an idea. I've done in Chrome, so I am not sure it is shown good in other browsers (simply because user-agent default styles are different) but it is easily fixable for every one.

HTML:

```
  <div class="currency">&pound;</div>

  <input>
```

CSS:

```
.currency {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 4px 7px;
}
```

Comment: To switch currency: `$("div.currency").text("$")` and that's it!